# Ruby print or return specific field from object

Tags: ruby

How do I print the `group_id` from the returned object?

The following is returned from a function. I want to print the `group_id` or maybe return the `group_id`

```rb
 {
  :security_groups=>[
    {
      :description=>"Created By ManageIQ",
      :group_name=>"MIQ_019",
      :ip_permissions=>[
        {
          :from_port=>22,
          :ip_protocol=>"tcp",
          :ip_ranges=>[
            {
              :cidr_ip=>"0.0.0.0/0",
              :description=>nil
            }
          ],
          :ipv_6_ranges=>[],
          :prefix_list_ids=>[],
          :to_port=>22,
          :user_id_group_pairs=>[]
        }
      ],
      :owner_id=>"943755119718",
      :group_id=>"sg-0c2c5f219f1bafc1a",
      :ip_permissions_egress=>[
        {
          :from_port=>nil,
          :ip_protocol=>"-1",
          :ip_ranges=>[
            {
              :cidr_ip=>"0.0.0.0/0",
              :description=>nil
            }
          ],
          :ipv_6_ranges=>[],
          :prefix_list_ids=>[],
          :to_port=>nil,
          :user_id_group_pairs=>[]
        }
      ],
      :tags=>[],
      :vpc_id=>"vpc-d817c1b3"
    }
  ],
  :next_token=>nil
}
```

This is the function: I want to `return security_group.group_id`

```
def describe_security_group (
  group_name
 )  
  ec2 = get_aws_client
  security_group = ec2.describe_security_groups(
    filters: [
      {name: 'group-name', values: [ group_name ]}]
    )
  puts "Describing security group '#{group_name}' with ID " \
    "'#{security_group}'"
  return security_group
rescue StandardError => e
  puts "Error describing security group: #{e.message}"  
  return 
end
```

Comment: How much elements can contain `security_groups` object? It always array of size 1 or can it be an unpredictable size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, returning value seems like a hash, or you can make it hash exactly.

For case with one-element array you can simple use ruby [dig](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/dig) method.

And according to your datum and comment below we can access needed element like this:

```rb
# from your ec2 api call
security_group  = ec2.describe_security_groups(...)

# Result value is stored in `security_group` variable,
# and looks exactly like hash below
{
  :security_groups=>[
    {
      :description=>"Created By ManageIQ",
      :group_name=>"MIQ_019",
      :ip_permissions=>[
        {
          :from_port=>22,
          :ip_protocol=>"tcp",
          :ip_ranges=>[
            {
              :cidr_ip=>"0.0.0.0/0",
              :description=>nil
            }
          ],
          :ipv_6_ranges=>[],
          :prefix_list_ids=>[],
          :to_port=>22,
          :user_id_group_pairs=>[]
        }
      ],
      :owner_id=>"943755119718",
      :group_id=>"sg-0c2c5f219f1bafc1a",
      :ip_permissions_egress=>[
        {
          :from_port=>nil,
          :ip_protocol=>"-1",
          :ip_ranges=>[
            {
              :cidr_ip=>"0.0.0.0/0",
              :description=>nil
            }
          ],
          :ipv_6_ranges=>[],
          :prefix_list_ids=>[],
          :to_port=>nil,
          :user_id_group_pairs=>[]
        }
      ],
      :tags=>[],
      :vpc_id=>"vpc-d817c1b3"
    }
  ],
  :next_token=>nil
}

# And this is a target value, that you can store in another one,
# return from method or simply print to output
security_group.dig(:security_groups)
              .try(:[], 0)
              .dig(:group_id)

=> "sg-0c2c5f219f1bafc1a"
```

But if you need to search in array with multiple elements, methods from [Ruby's Enumerable module](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html) could be helpful (like `select` or `reject`).

**UPDATE** with [OpenStruct](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html), if you prefer such method calls with dot notation:

```rb
json = security_group.to_json

os = JSON.parse(json, object_class: OpenStruct)

os.security_groups.first.group_id
=> "sg-0c2c5f219f1bafc1a"
```

Comment: There is no `sg_group_id` in the return data btw... It was a typo. The data starts with `{
    :security_groups`

Comment: Datum hash is a value of `security_group = ec2.describe_security_groups(...)`?

Comment: Yea. It seems like I can access it as `security_group.security_groups.first.group_id`

Comment: @John For this solution you need to use ruby OpenStruct with nested hashes handling, but it looks slightly overhanded. What is the problem with the `dig`?